# javascript 'setTimeout' function stops running after 6 minutes on Flask web server

Tags: javascript, flask, celery

*edit: I found a bug in Celery task which leads to this problem. So it's unrelated to that piece of JavaScript code blow. Suggest to close this question.

I have this Javascript function running on Flask web server, which checks status of a Celery task. If the task finished, console.log its result, otherwise recheck after 2 seconds.

It runs well if the Celery task finished in less than 6 minutes. However, when it hits the 6 minute mark, this function just stops running. The status of Celery task never updated again, even though I am sure that task is still running on the background, I don't receive any result from Javascript.

Is it a timeout setting of Flask? Any insights will be appreciated.

```
function update_progress(status_url) {
    // send GET request to status URL
    $.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
        if (data['state'] != 'PROGRESS') {
            if ('result' in data) {
                console.log(data['result']);
            }
            else {
                // something unexpected happened
                console.log(data['state']);
            }
        }
        else {
            // rerun in 2 seconds
            setTimeout(function() {
                update_progress(status_url);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: possibly 'something unexpected has happened' try to add a console.log(data) to see the raw data at each iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have done this. The data looks good. I can even manually go to the status_url to get the correct result after celery task finished.

Comment: Thanks for @Ibu made me double checked the 'correct result', which I thought, of the celery task. Then I found the problem, the result is not serializable, which leads $.getJSON failed. What makes things worse is $.getJSON failed silently. I found the error message by replacing $.getJSON failed with $.ajax(function(){...}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        console.log(xhr, status, error);
    })

Answer (score 2):

you could try use `setInterval` instead, registering it to a variable.

```
const updateInterval = setInterval(function(){
 update_progress(status_url);
},2000);
```

And inside `update_progress` function, remove the `else` part and add `clearInterval(updateInterval)`:

```
function update_progress(status_url) {
// send GET request to status URL
$.getJSON(status_url, function(data) {
    if (data['state'] == 'PROGRESS') {
        return;
    }

    clearInterval(updateInterval);

    if ('result' in data) {
        console.log(data['result']);
    }
    else {
        // something unexpected happened
        console.log(data['state']);
    }
});
```

}

Comment: It doesn't fix my problem. But I do agree that your code is the correct way and better practice to do the job. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Sorry =\ it's a very strange issue, can't think of anything.

Comment: By replacing $.getSON with $.ajax I found a problem in my backend code. $.getJSON failed silently really misleading me.